# works fine in one case / (column ambiguously defined)error in another

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables with a column named the same. Column is BAN_KEY

when I run this query

```
with 
t1 as
(
  select *
  from table1
),
t2 as
(
  select *
  from table2
)
t3 as
(
  select *
  from t1, t2
  where t1.c1 = t2.c2
)
select * from t3
```

I get error column ambiguously defined, but when I do it this way

```
with 
t1 as
(
  select *
  from table1
),
t2 as
(
  select *
  from table2
)
select *
from t1, t2
where t1.c1 = t2.c2
```

The result looks like this

```
BAN_KEY  |  BAN_KEY_1  |  other columns
some values...
```

What's the reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN`s.

That has nothing to do with your question.  The answer is much simpler.  For a CTE (or table), Oracle needs to be able to assign column names to the result so they can be access subsequently.  It accepts the column names that *you* provide, assuming that your intention is correct.  Duplicate column names are not allowed because the reference would be ambiguous; hence the error.

Why doesn't this happen for a result set?  Oracle does not require that the columns in the *result set* of a query be unique.  For convenience, though, it distinguishes between columns with the same name.

Comment: I would add to Gordon's insightful answer (which I upvoted) that the logical reason why a CTE cannot have duplicate column names is that because if this were permissible, then Oracle would have no way of knowing _which_ duplicate you wanted to use.  On the other hand, the columns of a terminal outer query won't be referenced by anything, so duplicates there are a moot point.